# Append value to n dimensional np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of dimension [755,25]
where 755 is the number of rows and 25 is the number of values in each row
I want to append a constant value say '6' to each row such that the resultant array has dimensions
as [755,512]

Please can anybody help with this?

Comment: How does add 1 value make the dimension goes from 25 to 512 ?

Comment: i want to add same value from 25 to 512

Comment: Enter the code you tried to write to solve this problem so that it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((755, 25))
b = np.zeros((755, 512))
b[:, :25] = a
b[:, 25:] = 6
```